# Firebase cloud function push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Currently I am subscribing every user to a single topic at every app startup && token refresh like so:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        let topic = "topic_for_user_with_id_" + user.uid
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: topic)
    }
}
```

Like this I can simply send notifications from cloud function:

```
const topic = `topic_for_user_with_id_${userId}`
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options);
```

Is there any drawbacks why I shouldn't use topics and send notifications directly to device tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no drawback, topics are normally used when alot of people are subscribed to a certain thing example `weather`. In this case it is better to use topics.

Sending notification using tokens, is usually done to a single person, not many people.

from the docs about Topics:

> Based on the publish/subscribe model, FCM topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. You compose topic messages as needed, and FCM handles routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices.

If you are sending a private notification then use tokens to send to that specific device, so not many people see what the private notification is about.

I think the only drawback with using topics is that the user needs to unsubscribe from the topic from his own phone since it is based on a public/subscribe model.

But I think this was solved in the `Admin FCM API`.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions

The above uses both topics and tokens, you will be able to unsubscribe users that are registered to a topic by just having there token.

Comment: @3vangelos if the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct,  so it helps other people, thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your answer!